# GestureRecognizer or Button Action not getting called for header view of section 0 of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, frame

I am experiencing a weird behaviour , following is my implementation of sectionHeaderView.

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 48)];
v.tag = section;
v.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 24, 24)];

UILabel* l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(64, 2, 200, 44)];
l.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f/255.0f green:51.0f/255.0f blue:51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

l.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu-Regular" size:16];

v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0f/255.0f green:242.0f/255.0f blue:242.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

[v addSubview:l];
[v addSubview:iv];
iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.tag = section;
btn.frame = CGRectMake(226, 19, 10, 10);
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_left.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[v addSubview:btn];

//--- did some modifications in UI ---///

UITapGestureRecognizer* g = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSectionHeader:)];
[v addGestureRecognizer:g];

UIButton* btnOverall = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnOverall.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 48);
btnOverall.tag = section;
[btnOverall addTarget:self action:@selector(moreButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[v addSubview:btnOverall];
btnOverall.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT; // so that button comes to top and is easily clickable.

UIView *singleLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 47, 256, 1)];
singleLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

[v addSubview:singleLineView];
return v;


}
```

the gesture recognizer is implemented this way:

```
- (void) tapSectionHeader:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)g {
self.selectedSection = g.view.tag;
//some code
}
```

But strangely neither tapSectionHeader: nor moreButtonClicked: are getting called for section 0 i.e. the "Homepage" option. It works perfectly fine for other section headers.

Note: seems to be an issue with tableview frame. Following is the way I am setting tableViewFrame:

```
CGRect screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
xAxis = 0;
yAxis = 48;
height = screenSize.size.height;
width = MENU_WIDTH;

self.frame = CGRectMake(-width, yAxis, width, height);
self.backgroundColor = BACKGROUND_COLOR;
if(!sender.navigationController.navigationBarHidden) {
    menuTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 256, height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}else {
    menuTable = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xAxis, yAxis, 256, height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
}
```

Here if yAxis = 48 it appears fairly below visible NavigationBar but button actions work fine. However, if yAxis = 0 , it is visible properly below NavigationBar but the touch interaction to section 0 header is not happening. So there's a dilemma for me here.

What should be the issue?

NOTE: navigationBar translucent property is set to NO. Hence, starting yAxis from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. Actually it was not even an issue with frame. It was an issue with which subview for the viewcontroller is on top! I was adding this view to as a subview for which I was also adding another view after an api call. However, this view was appearing on top  when doing view.layer.zPosition = MAXFLOAT. But this was done before another view was added. Hence, doing this after all subviews have been added helped!